# Flutter - How to display images in horizontal list view using listview builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I don't have much experience with flutter. I am trying to create a product list using listview builder.

I want to show header images in a horizontal list view.

I tried. But when I run it I continuously get the below error.

"Another exception was thrown: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..71: 72"

[image]

How to solve this? And **How to change the border color and width for the selected index?**

Code:

```
body: ((){
return  Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              const SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox(height: 20)),
              if (productController.section.value.docs != null)
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: 
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: productController.section.value.docs![brandsIndex!].items!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                            },
                            child:  
                                    Container(
                                      width: 50.0,
                                      height: 60.0,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color:
                                              const Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 252, 252),
                                          border: Border.all(
                                              width: 1,
                                              color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                                  255, 224, 224, 224),
                                                  ),
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                              image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                  productController.section.value
                                      .docs![brandsIndex!].items![index].imageUrl
                                      .toString())),
                                          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(15))),
                                    ),
                                 
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                ),
              
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
```

Comment: Are you sure that this line is correct ? `productController.section.value.docs![brandsIndex!].items!.length`. Also

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have changed it to "productController.section.value.docs![brandsIndex!].items!.length-1". Now it works.  How to change the border color and width for the selected index?

Comment: Just ask it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

productController.section.value.docs![brandsIndex!].items

This list is coming Empty. Apply the condition on this widget that (If list is not Empty then it will excute else you can give circular progressbar

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).